# Submit result.php into bootstrap Modal with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4

*Disclaimer: I checked stackoverflow posts over the past 3 days, i cannot find the exact answer to my question, please read before linking with an answered one*

---

**Problem**
I have a submit form, the user submits a `USD` number and it will convert to `BTC`.
The problem is, the user will be redirected to a new page, which is `converter.php`

**Solution**
Instead of redirecting to a new page (to `converter.php`)
We'd like to show the `converter.php` response with AJAX, into a modal after submit.

**index.php**

```
                 <form action="converter.php" method="post">
                    <h1>USD to BTC - Converter</h1>
                    <p>
                      <label for="amount">USD amount</label>
                      <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                      <label for="currency">Currency</label>
                      <select name="currency" id="currency">
                      <option value="USD">USD</option></select>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                   </p>
                </form>
```

**[converter.php](https://ghostbin.com/6VCWk/raw)**

---

### Example

Below is a very similar example of what i'd like to implement into my code above ⬆️
(Both work, i want to combine them and display php response in modal)

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form id="form" method="post">
    <div id="userDiv"><label>Type a number</label>
        
         <input type="text" name="userId" id="userId"/> <br></div>
    <button type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Send Data</button>
</form>


<!--modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">MyModal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
Here should echo response from the converter.php file
        <div id="bingo"></div>

      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn").click(function(){
            var vUserId = $("#userId").val();
         if(vUserId=='')
         {
             alert("Please enter a num");
         }
         else{
            $.post("result.php", //Required URL of the page on server
               { // Data Sending With Request To Server
                  user:vUserId,
               },
         function(response,status){ // Required Callback Function
             $("#bingo").html(response);//"response" receives - whatever written in echo of above PHP script.
             $("#form")[0].reset();
          });
        }
     });
   });
</script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

You can also pair this example with
[result.php](https://ghostbin.com/coebK/raw) to check the echo response

---

Comment: Create a function that does the conversion from USD to BTC and then make an AJAX call to that function with the value entered for conversion after which you can return the converted value into the modal.

Comment: Does all/some/none of this code work?

Comment: the code works, use index.php and converter.php , it will submit the form and redirect to converter.php showing the result, i want this result to display into the modal with AJAX

Comment: @BensonOkello a function with Js? Some pointers would help with that

Comment: Can you show what you get in network tab on inspect element?

Answer (score 0):

Change your input type from submit to button for prevent submitting the form

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When You Submit The Request Using Ajax In your success response first you need to open the modal then easily can change inputs on modal. Let me show you the example from your code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        var vUserId = $("#userId").val();
     if(vUserId=='')
     {
         alert("Please enter a num");
     }
     else{
        $.post("result.php", //Required URL of the page on server
           { // Data Sending With Request To Server
              user:vUserId,
           },
     function(response,status){ // Required Callback Function
         $("#Your Model ID").modal('show') //this will open modal automaticaly
         //Now use response to display on modal
         $("#input_box_1_id").val(response.inputbox1_val);
         //You can also render html from response like this
         $("#intened_id").html(response.html_content);
      });
    }
 });
  });
</script>
```

In this way, we can automatically open modal and display value in modal.
If further confusion you can ask.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sir, I'm not quite sure how I can take response from [converter.php](https://ghostbin.com/uUbGr/raw)  to display the conversion into the modal, would you be willing to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Yes, I check your converer.php file you are getting the whole response mix of content String and value.
You can like this in your success response function
$("#bingo").html(response);

Comment: Yes that is correct, i tried many things and couldn't work, both code examples above (first one and example) work individually, but i can't make them to work together as a result.

Comment: Could you share the response which you are getting from the ajax success function

Comment: You can get response using 
console.log(response);

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        var vUserId = $("#userId").val();
     if(vUserId=='')
     {
         alert("Please enter a num");
     }
     else{
        $.post("result.php", //Required URL of the page on server
           { // Data Sending With Request To Server
              user:vUserId,
           },
     function(response,status){ // Required Callback Function
         $("#myModal").modal('show')
         $("#bingo).html(response);
      });
    }
 });
  });
</script>

Comment: Use This one this is tested it is working.

Comment: It does not work with converter.php , i also think there is some syntax error, please edit the original answer

Comment: OK, I am re-editing original answer. Look at that